# If DHCP is not configured, then how to know IP address of WAP?

Tags: wireless-networking

I know the **SSID name and password** of the WiFi router. 
I have connected to it, by setting an arbitrary IP address, because **there are no DHCP servers** in the network (***automatic IP will not work***).
But I don't know the IP address of the wireless router.
How to find out the IP address of the wireless router in a network that does not have DHCP server ?

Comment: What's your Operating System? If it hapoens to be Linux, try the commands `iwlist` and `iwconfug` to get further on.

Comment: If the IP of the device is not set to the same network and subnet as the WiFi Router is setup, there will be no way to communicate with it (maybe you already know the network and subnet as @Gui suggested in his answer). Also, you could easily create a duplicate IP if you don't know all the IPs in this wireless network (also mentioned below). If you are not the administrator of this network you should ask the administrator what settings should be used. Are you sure there is no DHCP? Maybe it will give IPs only to registered MAC addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know what the network address and subnet mask is of the network the router is configured for. You could set your IP address to be static, in the same network. You may run into problems if it conflicts with another device. (From the sounds of it, you have gotten this far.)

Once connected, you can most likely use a ping based search application like [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/download/#windows) to find other devices on the network. Once you have identified the other devices, it is a matter of trial and error - attempt to connect to them and evaluate the outcome individually.

Note that the older version of Angry IP Scanner (Legacy on their download page) is simpler to use as it runs from its location and doesn't require Java or any third party components. Also, Virus scanners and smart screen filter may flag this as a hack tool.

[image: Angry IP Scanner Search Results]

As you can see from the image, you will find what hosts are available and which are not. The drawback of this method is that you must have layer 3 connectivity, and ping must be enabled (which usually is) on the local interfaces of the router you are searching for.